# Broadcast through redis stored sockets using sails

Tags: redis, socket.io, sails.js

I am developing an application with sails.js and I use sails.sockets.broadcast commands to send informations to multiple clients when actions are done.

This is working perfectly with the "memory" socket adapter. I change the configuration to test the "socket.io-redis" adapter in order to prepare the application scaling. The configuration for sails.config.sockets is :

```
 adapter: 'socket.io-redis',
 host: 'localhost',
 port: 6379,
 db: 'sails'
```

Now transmission through sockets from a client to the server, and response returned, are still working normally. But it appears that sails.sockets.broadcast does not work any more.

Is my configuration wrong ? Thank you for your time and your help.

Addition. When monitoring Redis, I see the periodic blast I try to send to client.

```
1478518664.574789 [0 127.0.0.1:38923] "publish" "socket.io#r4oExK" "\x92\x83\xa4type\x02\xa4data\x92\xa5blast\x81\xa7message\xa5blast\xa3nsp\xa1/\x82\xa5rooms\xc4\xa5flags\xc4"
```

But in the client I can't get the "blast" event.

```
io.socket.on('blast', function(data) {
  console.log('blast', data);
});
```

Comment: With a fresh sails installation, this was working, so I migrated my code to a fresh sails installation and it's now working ok. No idea what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating my socket.io-redis version to 1.1.1 from 0.1.4